# Composer with selinux system wide

Tags: software-installation

I have 5 users on ubuntu and want to install composer and other packages like phpmd for all of them.  I have installed composer in `/usr/local/bin/` .

phpmd installed with composer is in `~/.composer/vendor/bin/`. I have symlinked above path to `/usr/local/bin/compbin` and added it to `/etc/profile.d/comp.sh`

I can run phpmd and composer from everywhere. Other users can run composer but can't run any of the packages installed via composer.

I added all users to same group and `chmod -R 775 ~/.composer/venodr/bin/` but still get command not found. I can see that `/usr/local/bin/compbin` is in their path.

When I do `ls -Z` I don't see any context like others in `/usr/local/bin`. It is just question mark `?` instead of context.

What I am doing wrong? What is the best way to install composer and other packages system-wide?

If I try to run composer as root, it complains and does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working:

Set following in /etc/profile.d/comp.sh

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/composer/vendor/bin
export COMPOSER_HOME=/usr/local/composer
export COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR=/usr/local/composer/vendor
```

changed permissions and groups of /usr/local/composer

```
chown -R :users /usr/local/composer
chmod -R 775 /usr/local/composer
```

Everything is working as intended now.